# ids from MongoDB equals to undefined in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, interface, key

I try to fetch a list of items from MongoDB to a React app.

Items of an array of the list are retrieved from MongoDB, displayed in a component and the user can add new items (and save them in MongoDB).

The problem is that `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"` is shown because new elements are added to the list with a `key` attribute that equals to `undefined` (I'm trying to achieve is to use ids generated by MongoDB as `key`).

DynamicList.tsx (**WHEN expenseAndAmountList is consoled out inside  the items of the list in the array have a format of**  `{_id: "60cada13ae534110361f368b", expenseTitle: "er", expenseAmount: "4", __v: 0}` ( the first property is _id, none of the values are undefined))

```
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
  interface ListItemsArray {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    currencySymbol: string;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

  const DynamicList: React.FC<ListItemsArray> = (
    {
      expenseAndAmountList, 
      currencySymbol,
      setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: ListItemsArray) => {

    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {expenseAndAmountList.map(item => (
                  <ExpensesListItem
                    key={item.id}
                    expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} 
                    expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}
                    currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
                    item={item}
                    items={expenseAndAmountList}
                    setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
                  />
                ))} 
            </List>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default DynamicList;
```

ExpensesListItem.tsx (**HERE the values of prop id inside  = undefined**)

```
import React from "react";
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';

interface Props {
    expenseTitle: string;
    id: string;
    expenseAmount: string;
    currencySymbol: string;
    item: ExpenseAndAmountObject;
    items: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        id
    }: Props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={id}/>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

ExpenseAndAmountObject.tsx (**interface used at ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx**)

```
export interface ExpenseAndAmountObject {
    id: string,
    expenseTitle: string,
    expenseAmount: string,
}
```

I assume, the problem is that an object in the list that is fetched from the DB has an key `_id` (WITH UNDERSLASH) (e.g. `{_id: "60c97ae5ae534110361f359e", expenseTitle: "b", expenseAmount: "2", __v: 0}`) meanwhile the interface `ExpenseAndAmountObject` that I use to iterate through the list has a key `id`).

If I try to use `id={item._id}` at `DynamicList.tsx`, I get an error `"Property '_id' does not exist on type 'ExpenseAndAmountObject'."`

How could I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: to access `_id` use `._id`

Comment: Which place should I use it? If I try to use `id={item._id}` at `DynamicList.tsx`, I get an error `"Property '_id' does not exist on type 'ExpenseAndAmountObject'."`

Comment: well, perhaps you need to redefine `ExpenseAndAmountObject`

Comment: It worked! I've amended the id at `ExpenseAndAmountObject` and other places used, thanks!